# cURL: https through a proxy

Tags: php, python, curl, https, urllib2

I need to make a cURL request to a https URL, but I have to go through a proxy as well.  Is there some problem with doing this?  I have been having so much trouble doing this with curl and php, that I tried doing it with urllib2 in Python, only to find that urllib2 cannot POST to https when going through a proxy.  I haven't been able to find any documentation to this effect with cURL, but I was wondering if anyone knew if this was an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find testing with command-line curl a big help before moving to PHP/cURL.

For example, w/ command-line, unless you've configured certificates, you'll need `-k` switch. And to go through a proxy, it's the `-x <proxyhost[:port]>` switch.

I believe the `-k` equivalent is

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

I believe the `-x` equivalent is

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '<proxyhost[:port]>');
```

---

> *DISCLAIMER: I have not tested any of
>   this. If you give more information
>   about what you've tried, it might be
>   helpful.*

Answer (score 0):

No problem since the proxy server supports the CONNECT method.