# haskell Network.Curl access https behind proxy

Tags: haskell, https, proxy, libcurl

I'm trying to use `Network.Curl` to access an https resource behind an http proxy, but getting no luck.

I have the following configured:

```
export http_proxy=myhost:post
export https_proxy=myhost:port
```

I can verify that curl itself is capable of accessing an https resource through the proxy (no other way to get to it).

```
curl https://www.google.co.uk
```

There is nothing in ~/.curlrc.

I can access an http resource through the Curl bindings:

```
ghci> import Network.Curl
ghci> curlGetString "http://www.google.co.uk" []
```

Returns the source of google's homepage. However, if I change this to https, I get an error:

```
ghci> curlGetString "https://www.google.co.uk" []
(CurlHttpReturnedError,"")
```

Manually specifying a proxy through Curl.Opts seems to have no effect. How can I persuade `Network.Curl` to use the https proxy?

Edit: I've now discovered that it works if I specify 'CurlProxyUserPwd' manually. However, this doesn't seem to be required by curl on the command line, so the question is now "how do I manage to not require a username/password"?

Comment: I suspect the answer may lie in libcurl's docs rather than Haskell's library specifically. Could be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308760/curl-https-through-a-proxy

Comment: @ChristopherDone I think you're right - a friend of mine has come across the same thing with Python's bindings. Unfortunately it seems to be a difference between the command line client and libcurl itself.

Comment: I had a similar problem a few years ago and in the end used a Haskell binding for Selenium (browser automation). [It](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/selenium) has since been superseded by the [webdriver](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver) Selenium client for Haskell. It makes it easier because if your browser can get there so can your program, but an instance of the browser does need to be running.